# Is there a .NET method to grab the data source for an entity framework connection string?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to grab the data source from my connection string.  I know I can use

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString
```

and extract it out with regex.  But, it seems there should be an easy way to grab this data source.  I don't want to grab from character position because that would be fragile to any changes in the ordering of the string.

**UPDATE**
I am using entity framework 4.  The connection string is generated and begins with

```
metadata=res://*/
```

This appears to complicate things as the suggested object `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` throws error

> "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it hidden in the context.

```
EntityContextName context = new EntityContextName();
string datasourceName = context.Connection.DataSource;
```

Comment: Trying this with EF 4.1 in a WinForms .net4 application only shows my entities (tables). There isn't a method for Connection.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to do this (vb.net):

```
Dim varConnectionString = Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("iSAMDBEntities").ConnectionString
Dim ecb As EntityConnectionStringBuilder = New EntityConnectionStringBuilder(varConnectionString)
varConnectionString = ecb.ProviderConnectionString
Dim varBiulder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(varConnectionString)
varServidor = varBiulder.DataSource
varBaseDatos = varBiulder.InitialCatalog
varUsuario = varBiulder.UserID
varClave = varBiulder.Password
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting metadata error

> "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."

you can first use the *EntityConnectionStringBuilder* which can take connection string with metadata.

```
string connectionStringWithMetadata = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbEntities"].ConnectionString;
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionStringWithMetadata);
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);
// And now you can extract parts of the connection string
string dbUserName = connectionStringBuilder.UserID; 
string dbPassword = connectionStringBuilder.Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class that should get you what you want.

Have a look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947.aspx), this should get you close, here is the [full detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx), you will most likely just need to enumerate through the keys.

Comment: This looks very good, but I don't think it works with entity framework which of course I happen to be using.  I get error "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.".